# V-chip-group value is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I often run into this problem using the Vuetify v-chip-group.

I'm using the v-chip-group v-model, which is the selected chip index.

```
<v-chip-group
  v-model="selectedItem"
>
```

I set the value to -1 so by default so no v-chip is selected

```
        data() {
            return {
                selectedItem: -1,
            }
        }
```

The problem I encounter is when a v-chip is selected, it changes the value from its default, but when this v-chip item is deleted from the list, the selectedItem value becomes undefined.

Is there a way to put back the value to -1 in the cases where there isn't any selected chip ?

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the value and then reset it, but I'm wondering why you want this behaviour? Is it because you need to evaluate if the value is -1 so that you can do something else? I'm asking because I feel it makes sense for the component to set its value to 'undefined' when it is deselected.

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedItem: -1
  };
},
watch: {
  selectedItem(v) {
    console.log(v);
    if (!v) {
      this.selectedItem = -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using ```:disabled = "selectedItem === -1"``` on other components. This doesn't work if I have an undefined.

Comment: @Philx94 I guess you can just use `:disabled = "!selectedItem"` if you also choose to use an empty value in your data block for selectedItem like `selectedItem: ""`

Comment: for some reason, the selected chip with index 0, count as a ```!selectedItem```. Why 0 is false ?

Comment: @Philx94 This happens for some programming languages. like 0 in C is also considered false. This is why you should specify customized values for each option. just add `<v-chip value="option1"></v-chip>` will solve the problem. This also helps to document the code.